# Help in creating a single library by combining/merging other libraries

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a couple of queries out here before I start creating my custom library to include methods, models, properties, etc which are commonly used by the different in-house applications that my company uses.

**Question 1:** how can I implement a number of libraries in a class library I am planning to create? The concept is explained below:

**Library Setup:** I am trying combine the following into one `DLL` file:

**1:** Extension Methods

**2:** Object Relational Model

**3:** Common Database Queries Used

and wondering if I could call them like the defaults ones: example `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(variable)`, `System.String.Join(variable)` etc.

I want to use the `DLL` methods, models, queries, etc based on the namespace provided in my various application as follows:

```
using CompanyLibrary.Extensions;
using CompanyLibrary.Models;
using CompanyLibrary.Queries;
```

Based  on the namespace specified, I can use their members, methods, properties.

I know how to create `DLL` files for separate Projects that will give me `Extensions.dll`, `Models.dll`, `Queries.dll`.

**Main Question:** How do I merge all the `dll's` into a single `dll`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to create a single library project with multiple namespaces in different folders.

Comment: Yes, I want to do that. How do I accomplish it. Currently, I have 3 different projects in one solution that produces different dll's on build. I just need one parent dll to hold the others.

Comment: Move all of the files into subfolders of one project, and change the `namespace`s to suit your needs.

Answer (score 3):

Are you just looking for [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx)?

Comment: I want to merge all dll's into one. How do I accomplish it. Currently, I have 3 different projects in one solution that produces different dll's on build. I just need one parent dll to hold the others. I will have a look at the link that you posted.

Comment: @reggie: Yes, if you read the linked project page, it will tell you exactly how to accomplish it...

Comment: +1 for the tool. But in this case, I will go with Slaks solution. Thanks for your time